# Subscription charge at the beginning of the month for the previous month of service.

Tags: stripe-payments

The way Stripe works, it seems, is that when I assign a subscription to a customer it will automatically try and charge that customer immediately. Then, any invoice items I add in that given month, it seems will be charged at the beginning of the next cycle aka the 2nd month.

What I am trying to do is this:

A customer signs up for a subscription and instead of charging the user, it creates a pending invoice. I can then add other invoice items to this over the course of the month and at the end of the billing cycle (instead of the beginning) actually charge the user for the previous month of service.

Is this possible? Because I can not for the life of me figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to have a subscription amount at all? You can certainly create a $0 plan which will be billed each month along with any invoice items you created during the preceding month.

If you do want a subscription amount but want it billed at the end of the first month, you could create a plan with a 30-day free trial. You can add invoice items in the intervening month and then the subscription (along with corresponding invoice items) will be billed for the first month 30 days after signup.

Comment: Hmm the trial thing is a good idea, although if the user cancels before the month is over I get nothing for my resources.